# sys_read syscall vs. int 0x80 in GNU Assembler

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, system-calls, gnu-assembler

I'm attempting to write a simple program which grabs a number of characters from stdin. For the sake of brevity, the relevant code is:

```
mov $3, %rax    # sys_read = 3
mov $0, %rbx    # stdin fd = 0
mov $b, %rcx    # '.lcomm b, 32' declared in .bss section
mov $32,%rdx    # size_t
# syscall
int $0x80
```

When I use `int $0x80` the program functions as intended, however with `syscall` it segfaults. I read that it has something to do with the fact that using an interrupt requires the kernel to remember the state of the machine, while `syscall` does not honour that requirement, i.e., the kernel handles it in its own time. I'm not sure if this is the real reason - I would assume that `syscall` does something to the registers such that `sys_read` fails.

I also read from a previous question posted here that "`syscall` is the default way of entering the kernel" and that "`int 0x80` is the legacy way to invoke a system call and should be avoided." ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806584/what-is-better-int-0x80-or-syscall))

I can't really find any good documentation on this, so any input would be appreciated.

Edit: typo

Comment: `syscall` should work on a 64-bit system, but you need different sys_call numbers and parameters in different registers. Funny how `int 80h` is not recommended... but seems to work - even on a 64-bit system! You've got a "mixed bag" of 64-bit registers and 32-bit system call numbers and parameters.

Comment: Ahh okay, thank you. The $b and $0 go into registers rsi and rdi, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510333/x86-64-assembly-linux-system-call-confusion) question. On x86_64 the correct exit system call is `$60` which should be in `%rax`.

```
 mov $60, %rax
 mov $0, %rdi 
 syscall
```