# Allocate heap memory in 64-bit assembler

Tags: assembly

I was wondering if any one could explain in relatively simple terms, how to allocate heap memory?

I'm using x64 assembler (intel syntax) on a Linux machine. Up until now I have relied on making a call to the C function `malloc`, but I'm interest in the proper way.

Comment: The days when you could just claim any physical memory you wanted are long gone (think DOS). AFAIK dynamically allocated memory is allocated for a program by the operating system, so I'd guess you *do* have to make some sort of system call. What OS are you using?

Comment: Unless you are a very advanced programmer - I mean Master Yoda level - "proper way" to allocate memory in C **is** using the malloc(), not assembly. It's not a trival  operation, just check out Doug Lea's article about his malloc implementation at http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html  . Not to mention the low portability issue.

Comment: There are multiple ways. Read about `sbrk()` for the old-fashioned way to allocate heap memory and read about `mmap()` for the modern way which is more complex to get right but also more flexible.

Comment: For posteriority: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586532/assembly-x86-brk-call-use/44876873#44876873

Answer (score 2):

There are syscall lists available online that give you parameters to call directly (instead of the C function).  Example list: http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64  Example usage: http://callumscode.com/blog/3

Comment: Specifically, the syscall you want is `brk` or `sbrk`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988487/what-does-brk-system-call-do . Real life implementations of malloc() allocate large chunks at a time, and then manage those.