# Writing to allocated memory with sbrk results in segfault

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, sbrk

I'm trying to allocate memory with `sys_brk` and here is the program:

```
BYTES_TO_ALLOCATE equ 0x08

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, 12 ;sys_brk number
    mov rdi, BYTES_TO_ALLOCATE
    syscall

    mov cl, 0x00 ;setting the value I need
    mov [rax], byte 0x01 ;SegFault
    mov rax, 60
    syscall
```

As specified in the [linux manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html)

> `sbrk()` increments the program's data space by increment bytes.
>   Calling `sbrk()` with an increment of 0 can be used to find the current
>   location of the program break.

I segfaulted when runnning the program. The register content before the segfaulted `mov` was:

```
rax            0x401000 4198400
rbx            0x0      0
rcx            0x40008c 4194444
```

I also tried to decrement the `rax` value as follows:

```
BYTES_TO_ALLOCATE equ 0x08

_start:
    mov rax, 12 ;sys_brk number
    mov rdi, BYTES_TO_ALLOCATE
    syscall

    mov rbx, rax
    dec rbx
    mov [rbx], byte 0x01 ;Again SegFault
    mov rax, 60
    syscall
```

Now, I'm kind of confused how to use `sys_brk` return value. I took it from [***here***](http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/). I also tried to use value in `rcx` but segfaulted anyway.

Comment: RCX is not part of the return value from the syscall. [SYSCALL](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSCALL.html) instruction itself clobbers RCX and R11 (RCX happens to contain the address of the instruction after the SYSCALL and R11 is a copy of RFLAGS. Using RCX is pretty useless.

Comment: [The value in `rcx` = RIP, which you already know from my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983371/why-do-x86-64-linux-system-calls-modify-rcx-and-what-does-the-value-mean).  Your program text is in a read-only page, so of course a store to `[rcx]` segfaulted.  RAX is the return value, and RCX + R11 are clobbered, stop worrying about what's in RCX.

Comment: `sys_brk` *sets* the program break, it doesn't *increment* it.  See [the only good answer on the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44876873/224132).  Your system call with a small integer as the pointer arg may have unmapped all heap pages (at least the ones in the brk area), if there were any to start with.

Comment: When single-stepping, look at `/proc/PID/smaps` to see what regions are mapped before/after the system call.

Comment: @PeterCordes Understood, many thanks!