# Injected mprotect system call into traced process fails with EFAULT

Tags: c, linux, ptrace, mprotect

I'm injecting an `mprotect` call into a traced process:

```
static int inject_mprotect(pid_t child, void *addr, size_t len, int prot)
{
    // Machine code:
    //  int $0x80       (system call)
    //  int3            (trap)
    char code[] = {0xcd,0x80,0xcc,0};
    char orig_code[3];
    struct user_regs_struct regs;
    struct user_regs_struct orig_regs;

    // Take a copy of current state
    __check_ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child, NULL, &orig_regs);
    getdata(child, INSTRUCTION_POINTER(regs), orig_code, 3);

    // Inject the code, update registers
    putdata(child, INSTRUCTION_POINTER(regs), code, 3);
    __check_ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child, NULL, &regs);
    XAX_REGISTER(regs) = MPROTECT_SYSCALL;
    MPROTECT_ARG_START(regs) = (unsigned long)addr;
    MPROTECT_ARG_LEN(regs) = len;
    MPROTECT_ARG_PROT(regs) = prot;   
    __check_ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, child, NULL, &regs);

    // Snip
```

However the call fails, returning -14 (`EFAULT`).  I've looked through the `mprotect` source (kernel 3.13) and can't see why my system call would return this.

If I trace my injected call and print out the registers I see the following:

```
SIGTRAP: eip: 0x34646ef8d4, syscall 10, rc = -38
PARENT 10 MPROTECT(start: 0x00007f45b9611000, len: 4096, prot: 0)
EIP: 0x00000034646ef8d4 AX: 0xffffffffffffffda  BX: 0x0000000000000005  CX: 0xffffffffffffffff
 DX: 0x0000000000000000 DI: 0x00007f45b9611000  BP: 0x00007fffcb93bc20  SI: 0x0000000000001000
 R8: 0x0000000000000000 R9: 0x0000000000000000  R10: 0x0000000000000000
SIGTRAP: eip: 0x34646ef8d4, syscall 10, rc = -14 Bad address (trap after system call exit)
```

To validate the system call format I added an `mprotect` call to the child and dumped out its arguments and registers:

```
SIGTRAP: eip: 0x34646ef927, syscall 10, rc = -38
CHILD  10 MPROTECT(start: 0x00007f45b9611000, len: 4096, prot: 0)
EIP: 0x00000034646ef927 AX: 0xffffffffffffffda  BX: 0x0000000000000005  CX: 0xffffffffffffffff
 DX: 0x0000000000000000 DI: 0x00007f45b9611000  BP: 0x00007fffcb93bc20  SI: 0x0000000000001000
 R8: 0x000000000000004e R9: 0x746f72706d206c6c  R10: 0x00007fffcb93b9a0
SIGTRAP (child return): eip: 0x34646ef927, syscall 10, rc = 0
```

The call from the child succeeds.  So given that I'm making the same system call (10) with the same arguments, why does the injected call fail with `EFAULT` while a call from the child is successful?

The only difference between the calls is some junk in `regs.r8`, `regs.r9` and `regs.r10`, however based [this table of system calls on X86_64](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64) I don't believe the contents of those registers would affect the system call.

Comment: Just a wild guess: Maybe this is related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510333/x86-64-assembly-linux-system-call-confusion) question? (Curious, because your link says that syscall 10 is 64bit mprotect, but `int 0x80` is 32bit syntax)

Comment: @Phillip thanks that sounds very promising - been focussed on making the system call itself and the arguments architecture independent that I didn't think about `int 0x80` vs `syscall`!

Comment: @Phillip you were right, it was because I was using the 32-bit system call.  This is now resolved and I've pushed my working code to [github](https://github.com/potentialventures/cocotb/commit/d85ee802248395547ef51aef8c37f3837ab32811).  Can you post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Great, done. (And thanks for the link. Both the overall project and your mmap trap look quite interesting.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510333/x86-64-assembly-linux-system-call-confusion): i386 and x86_64 use different calling conventions for system calls. Your example code uses `int 0x80`, the i386 variant, but `syscall_number = 10`, the 64-bit syscall number for `mprotect`. In 32-bit environments, syscall 10 coresponds to `unlink`, according to [this list](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html), which *can* return `EFAULT` (`Bad address`).

On 64-bit platforms, using either the 32-bit or 64-bit variant in a consistent manner solves the problem.